# CTRL+C stopped working from LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

I still use 18.04. Some time this month Ctrl+C stopped working in LibreOffice. It copies internally in the program but I cannot paste in another program. If I click Copy in its context menu, it works. I tried setting the LibreOffice's shortcut to Copy, this did not help.

LibreOffice version: 6.0.7.3

Comment: please [edit] your question to include the version of LO you are using

Comment: Also, strangely, it started working again now, so this is apparently not deterministic.

Comment: LibreOffice has many bugs with copy & paste. If you search AskUbuntu on "LO copy and paste problems", you find find many similar questions.